# Looping through 2 arrays (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Player Resources and Required Resources follow a similar pattern;

```
public struct RequiredResources
    {
        public Resource resource;
        public int quantityRequired;
    }

    public class Resource : ScriptableObject
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private string resourceName;
        public string GetName() { return resourceName; }

        [SerializeField]
        public Sprite icon;
        public Sprite GetIcon() { return icon; }
    }
```

The resources available to the player are as follows;
Food, Gold, Wood, Stone

I wish to use a system like this so I can easily add more resources as needed. When a building is placed it has a list of resources required to build it, for example a house may cost;
Gold = 5
Wood = 3

With the code below this will loop through the resources and reduce the amount as required. Basically the amount the player has - the cost, then update the UI.

```
public void UseResources()
    {
        foreach (RequiredResources requiredResources in building.GetResources())
        {
            foreach (ResourceManager.PlayersResources resource in player.playersResources)
            {
                if (requiredResources.resource.Equals(resource.GetResourceType()))
                {
                    resource.RemoveQuantity(requiredResources.quantityRequired);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, before running this I want to check if the player even has enough resources. When I use a similar logic to return true and false, and the player has enough wood (true) but not enough gold (false), it will remove the amount for both. I am at such a loss as to a way to do this correctly.

```
public bool HasRequiredResources(RequiredResources[] requiredResources)
    {
        foreach (RequiredResources r in requiredResources) //go through all required resources
        {
            foreach (PlayersResources p in playersResources)
            {
                if (r.quantityRequired > p.GetCurrAmount())
                    Debug.Log("Has enough " + r.resource.name);
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true; //reaching this point means that the faction has all required resources
    }
```

This is what I have but it always return false, where am I going wrong? I believe this is due to the foreach inside of the foreach. But how can I run the search of the second (PlayersResources) list to return the same Resource?

Comment: surely its printing out then, "Has enough"?  What Im going to guess is if you have 1 sugar, 2 flour, and it checks 2 flour its saying no to the 1 sugar, as its not checking the sugar and the flour are the same resource type......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your inner foreach loop is not checking whether the two resources are the same kind.  You're checking if the user has 5 gold when the required resource is just 5 wood, for example.

Add an if statement inside that second foreach loop to check, perhaps something like `if (p.resourceName == r.resource.name) { ...`

You might also experiment with LINQ syntax.  I'm not sure of the names of the fields in your classes, but it seems like something like this would work for you:

```
return requiredResources.All(r =>
    playersResources.Any(p => r.resource.resourceName == p.resource.resourceName &&
       r.quantityRequired > p.GetCurrAmount())   
);
```

Basically, this means:  Return true if, for every r in requiredResources, there is at least one p in playersResource that has the same resourcename as r and has an adequate amount.

Comment: Thank you for this! So simple and so effective! I have yet to delve into Linq but I am surely going to be researching into this. Thank you so much for your help and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your error is because you have not included the return statement in the if clause. So the foreach always returns false. Just as a best practice, you should always use curly braces with if statements. This will save you hours of debugging.
Try this...

```
foreach (PlayersResources p in playersResources)
{
    if (r.quantityRequired > p.GetCurrAmount())
        {
            Debug.Log("Has enough " + r.resource.name);
            return false;
        }
}
```

Don't understand the Debug.Log logic though...

Comment: I believe you are right, I was drawing such a blank yesterday and now visiting with a fresh pair of eye I have seen my mistake! However there is a very effective solution suggested by jgfoot utilising Linq for those interested. Thank you very much for your time and help Euler!

Comment: Happy to help. Coding get harry sometimes.